# Coloring a specific cell in a column inside a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

Ok, I ave been trying to this for the past dew hours and it is becoming hopeless.

So I want to apply the cell render to the 2nd column.

```
stockTable.setCellRender(jtSpread.getColumnModel().getColumn(1));
```

The method called is setCellRender which has the following code:

```
public void setCellRender(TableColumn column)
{
    column.setCellRenderer(new cellRenderer(data, rows));
}
```

My CellRenderer class has the following code:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

  for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      if(row == i && column == 2) {

      }
  }
  return this;
}
```

The above is incomplete and in a complete mess. My aim is to check each cell for a condition, if true then I would return the label with a foreground of green. If false, return the label with a foreground of red. I want to check EVERY CELL in the column, one by one and each condition is specific to each cell.

EDIT: With regard to each cell having its own condition, for eg.

The first cell has a value of 600, and I want to check against an array[0], if the contents of array[0] are higher I want the cell to be green, otherwise red.

The second cell has value of 626, and I want to check against an array[1], if the contents of the array[1] are higher, I want the cellt o be green, otherwise red.

I want to continue for all cells in the column against all values in the array

Comment: So each cell's condition is different? Across the whole table or just across the column?

Comment: your approach is wrong: a renderer is concerned _only_ about the cell that is is about to render. Be sure you understand that concept, f.i. by reading a basic tutorial, like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your renderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer:

```
CellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
   ...
```

Then, `getTableCellRendererComponent()` might look like this (this method is called each time the a cell is rendered):

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, 
    boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

    Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
          table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
     cellComponent.setForeground(isMyConditionFullfilled(value) ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED);
     return cellComponent;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your render class must implement TableCellRender
Try this in your render class:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setOpaque(true);
        if (value != null && value.equals("text")) { //Checking if  cell´s values isnt null and the condition is true
            label.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }else{
            label.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
        return label;
    }
```

The render will check each cell by his own, just tell it how to render each cell. The variable "value" contains the value for each row, so you can use it to check the condition. If your column has a type defined, cast the variable "value".
For example if you cell has Double type defined:

```
double valDouble = (Double) value;
if (value != null && value == 5.00) { //Checking if  cell´s values isnt null and the condition is true
        label.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
 }else{
        label.setBackground(Color.RED);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, please check my original post which I've justupadated. I've included the checks I want to carry out for each cell, please check and let me know if there is a way to accommodate this,

Comment: One of the problems with modifying your original post and giving a vague comment about it to explain is that we can no longer tell what your remaining question is.  Did neither of these posts answer your question?  In what way did they not answer it?  I think it would be better to make another answer in this thread, so a reader could come and see that you referred to a, b, and c in the original, and they answered a and part of b, but you were looking for c...

Comment: -1 for creating a new JLabel each time the renderer is called (that's _often_) Instead, create it once, f.i. in the constructor and then re-use.